# Determine some sequence is convergent or not, if not does it has a convergent subsequence$?$

Tags: sequences-and-series, multivariable-calculus

> For each sequence with $j>0$ and general term $a_j$ given, determine if it is convergent, not convergent but has a convergent subsequence, or has no convergent subsequence.
>
> $1.\space a_j=(\frac{\cos(\pi j)}{2},\frac{\sin(\pi j)}{2},\sqrt{j})$
>
> $2.\space a_j=(\frac{1}{j},1-\sin(\pi j))$
>
> $3.\space a_j=(\frac{\cos(j)}{j},\frac{\sin(j)}{j})$
>
> $4.\space a_j=(\cos(j),\sin(j),e^{−j})$
>
> $5. \space a_j=(j\cos(\frac{πj}{2}),(−1)^j)$

---

My attempts

For $1.$, seems not convergent

[image: 1]

For $2.$, seems not convergent

[image: 2]

For $3.$, convergent

[image: 3]

For $4.$, seems not convergent

[image: 4]

For $5.$, seems not convergent

[image: 5]

For those seems like not convergent, how do I know if it has a convergent subsequence, actually I'm not quite sure if I do understand what is a subsequence yet, here is my question about [subsequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3387836)

Is it possible to solve this kind of questions by solving limits or some kind of calculations$?$

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The third component if $\sqrt j$. Since $\left(\sqrt j\right)_{j\in\mathbb N}$ growths to $\infty$, it has no convergent subsequence. Therefore, $(a_j)_{j\in\mathbb N}$ has no convergent subsequence.
2. $\displaystyle\lim_{j\to\infty}a_j=(0,1)$.
3. $\displaystyle\lim_{j\to\infty}a_j=(0,0)$.
4. The sequence $\bigl(\cos(j)\bigr)_{j\in\mathbb N}$ doesn't converge and therefore your sequence doesn't converge. But it is bounded and therefore, by the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem, it has a convergent subsequence.
5. It diverges, but the subsequence $(a_{4j+1})_{j\in\mathbb N}$ converges to $(0,-1)$.

Answer (score 1):

1): not convergent, has no convergent subsequence

2) converges to $(0,1)$

3) converges to $(0,0)$

4) not convergent, has a convergent subsequence

5) not convergent, has a convergent subsequence

For the last one you have to consider a subsequence along which the first coordinate is $0$.

For 4) use the fact that any bounded sequence has a  convergent subsequence.